# JWT Token Refresh Invoking

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I understand how to use JWT tokens for authentication/authorization. However, there is not a specific method call or event that invokes the code to provide a new token at the path "/token" using the refresh token. Please answer, does the code below get called automatically behind-the-scenes by NPM package 'jsonwebtoken' when the token expires, or is there a manual way to call this that I am missing in the tutorials?

```
let refreshTokens = []; //in production use redis or other...

app.post('/token', (req, res) => {
    const refreshToken = req.body.token;
    if (refreshToken == null) return res.sendStatus(401);
    if (refreshTokens.includes(refreshToken)) return res.sendStatus(403);
    jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
        const accessToken = generateAccessToken({ name: user.name });
        res.json({ accessToken: accessToken });
    })
})
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean by "automatically behind-the-scenes". `jwt.verify` "happens" once immediately after being invoked. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, I understand that .verify() is a keyword. My question is, when does this POST method run and how is it invoked? Obviously the users are not ever hitting the URL <website>/token.

Comment: Given a lot of assumptions, this code runs whenever there is an incoming `POST /token` request, - not necessarily triggered manually by the user (e.g., there's a [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) function)

Comment: `if (refreshTokens.includes(refreshToken)) return res.sendStatus(403);` - so it's an error if the passed in refreshToken exists?

Comment: I believe that line means if the refresh token exists in the array don't run the rest of the block repeatedly. Maybe that's the answer- is this POST method behaving like an IIFE and throttled by the 403? The problem, @Dima Parzhitsky, is I can't find that ```fetch()``` anywhere and obviously users do not use that route.

Answer (score 1):

The post method you have created will never going to execute automatically because as we know http protocol works on request and response model unit and unless we will not give a request its not going to execute and after giving response it close their connection

read this article it will help you

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/06/17/nodejs-mongodb-api-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens

Comment: Thanks, I read that article this past weekend. I have the guy forked on Github from a few months ago. Can you please help me understand, where is that POST method called in the JWT flow? I always read the code of tutorials and can never find the actual invocation of the request.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, this is more of a communication error. Usually JWT token ecosystems are taught as a server-side process without mentioning that the refresh endpoint is called by the client side from an event like a login form, just like any other server side endpoint. Here is a good example of a complete tutorial of the JWT process. It is simple with that being said.

https://github.com/manosriram-youtube/jwt-auth